# Python-Plotting Temperature as a function of Depth over a period of time

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gradient

I'm relatively new to python and am currently working to analyze some oceanographic data. I'm trying to create a plot of temperature data at various depths over a period of time. I intend of creating a graph which appears similar to this:

[image: time versus depth with colors for the temperature of ocean]

Any assistance will be wonderfully appreciated. I have been research matplotlib's contourf function but really don't know where to even start.

Comment: Is the data in netcdf format? What have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Comment: This question is _way_ to general.  That particular plot is probably from `countourf`  http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html